# How to search an array in PHP basing on a condition

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

If I have an array like this:

```
 $cars = array (
 array("name"=>"jeep","Year"=>"2012"),
 array("name"=>"ferrari","Year"=>"2017"),  
 array("name"=>"jaguar","Year"=>"2013")
);
```

How to print a `$cars['name']` where `$cars[Year] = 2013`, is that possible in the array as we can do in MySQL? As we know with MySQL we can do:

```
select * from table where //condition
```

So, how this can be done in arrays?

Comment: If you really need to use SQL style syntax, then you need an implementation of LINQ in PHP, otherwise just use [array_filter()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could loop through each element in the array and using an 'if' statement echo the name of the car if the year is 2013

```html
$cars = array (
 array("name"=>"jeep","Year"=>"2012"),
 array("name"=>"ferrari","Year"=>"2017"),  
 array("name"=>"jaguar","Year"=>"2013")
);

foreach ($cars as $value) {

  if($value[Year] == 2013){
    echo $value[name] ."<br>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array_filter()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) and pass an conditional function as the second argument along with your array. As an example in your case:

```
function filterArray($value){
    if($value['Year'] == "2013")
         return $value['name'];
}

$filteredArray = array_filter($fullArray, 'filterArray');
```

So if we passed an array that looks like:

```
 $fullArray = array (
 array("name"=>"John","Year"=>"2012"),
 array("name"=>"Doe","Year"=>"2017"),  
 array("name"=>"Martin","Year"=>"2013")
);
```

Output would be:

```
Array
(
    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => Martin
            [Year] => 2013
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

And also solution with [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php), because you will probably have multiple cars with same year.

```
$cars = array (
 array("name"=>"jeep","Year"=>"2012"),
 array("name"=>"ferrari","Year"=>"2017"),  
 array("name"=>"jaguar","Year"=>"2013")
);

$filtered_cars = array_filter($cars, function ($item) {
    return $item['Year'] === '2013';
});

print_r(current($filtered_cars)['name']);
```

Answer (score 0):

An example with the isFromYear function accepting the year as a parameter:

```
<?php
$cars = array (
     array("name"=>"jeep","Year"=>"2012"),
     array("name"=>"ferrari","Year"=>"2017"),
     array("name"=>"jaguar","Year"=>"2013")
);

class YearFilter {
    private $year;

    function __construct($year) {
            $this->year = $year;
    }

    function isFromYear($i) {
            return $i["Year"] == $this->year;
    }
}

$matches = array_filter($cars, array(new YearFilter("2013"), 'isFromYear'));
print_r($matches);

?>
```